# ng-repeat from a list of lists

Tags: .net, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I got the current data structure that I want to print out in a list:

```
public class Topic
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<FAQ> FAQs { get; set; }
}


public class FAQ
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Question { get; set; }
    public string Answer { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public int Likes { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int TopicID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("TopicID")]
    public virtual Topic Topic { get; set; }

}
```

In my angular-controller I receive a list of Topics with a list of FAQs and bind it to $scope.topics.

I already printed out all FAQs under their Topic with nested ng-repeat.

Now I want to make a "Top 10" list, with the top 10 FAQs with the most likes. Something like:

```
<ol ng-repeat="faq in faqs(topic.FAQs in topic) | orderBy: 'Likes'">
    <li>{{ faq.Question }} - {{ faq.Likes }}</li>
</ol>
```

I'm having a hard time how to extract a collection of all my FAQs. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

If i get your answer right I'm doubting you can do that from the view, but perhaps a Watcher in the controller can do the trick, of course this assuming constant changes in your structure of topics as faqs, something like:

assuming a json structure

{ topics: { id: 1, name: 'asd', FAQs: [{Likes: 324, ...},{...},...] }, {...}, ... }

```
$scope.topics = [...]; // A collection like above
$scope.top_faqs = [];
$scope.$watchCollection('topics', function(){
    var i = $scope.topics.length;

    while(i--){ //Use while for faster loops
        var j = $scope.topics[i].FAQs.length;
        while(j--){
           $scope.top_faqs.push(topics[i].FAQs[j]);
        }
    }
    // Inject $filter in your controller as a dependency
    $scope.top_faqs = $filter('orderBy')($scope.top_faqs, 'Likes', false);
    $scope.top_faqs = $filter('limitTo')($scope.top_faqs, 10);
});
```

Now in your view you can simply do a regular ng-repeat for the `$scope.top_faqs`

```
<ol ng-repeat="faq in top_faqs">
    <li>{{ faq.Question }} - {{ faq.Likes }}</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Hello and thanks for your reply! I get the error "ReferenceError: $filter is not defined".

Comment: Didn't know I had to inject it into my controller. Got everything working now! I dropped the `$watchCollection` part and put your logic inside `function updateTop10()`, so when a FAQ is Liked, the list will be reordered.

Comment: One more thing. I had to add `$scope` before `topics` in your function/callback: `var i = $scope.topics.length`

Comment: glad it help you i suppose th code got its quirks since it just wrote it on the fly :P